# IIS Powershell : Assign an existing SSL binding to a website

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7, powershell

I already have an SSL binding created for one of my websites in IIS 7.5.

Now I'm adding another website which listens on the same IP and port (443) but uses a different host header.

When I try to assign the binding using this powershell command:

```
New-WebBinding -Name $siteName -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https -HostHeader $hostHeader
```

OR

```
New-ItemProperty $sitePath -name bindings -value @{protocol="https";bindingInformation=":443:"+$hostHeader}
```

I get the following error in Powershell.

```
SSL binding for end point 0.0.0.0:443 already exists.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Item], ProviderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SSL binding for end point 0.0.0.0:443 already ex
   ists.,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

You get rid of the error by making a more specific binding. You currently have an SSL binding, on another website, bound to all IP addresses.

IIS 7.5 does not support [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), so this is your only option. Without SNI you cannot have host name headers for SSL; you need one IP address per certificate.

Comment: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html  Would this work?

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting way of doing it. Yes and no. It still uses the *same* certificate on multiple sites, with SAN's on the certificate that it can just service the default certificate without thinking about it. I was not aware of this - perhaps this is what the op is trying to do...